# How to change OPTIMIZER_MODE setting in oracle?

Tags: oracle

How to change OPTIMIZER_MODE setting in oracle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change OPTIMIZER_MODE, with alter command as shown below,

```
alter session set OPTIMIZER_MODE = RULE;
alter session set OPTIMIZER_MODE = choose;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
ALTER SESSION SET OPTIMIZER_MODE  = RULE;
```

or if you need to make changes for all system:

```
ALTER SYSTEN SET OPTIMIZER_MODE = RULE SCOPE=SPFILE;
```

Use

```
 SELECT VALUE FROM v$parameter WHERE NAME = 'optimizer_mode'
```

to check the result.

Answer (score 0):

If your users have a pattern in their username, you can do something like this:

```
create or replace  trigger set_optimizer_mode
after logon
on database
begin
    if user like 'WHS_%' then
        execute immediate 'alter session set optimizer_mode=all_rows';
    end if;
end;
/
```